# PDO, Accented letters (ñ, é, etc) in a mysql database showing up as question marks

Tags: php, pdo

I am using PDO to update and retrieve results from a mysql database.

When I retrieve words with accented letters, the accented letters show up as question marks. When I browse the mysql database with phpmyadmin, the accented letters show up perfectly.

What do I do?

Thanks

Comment: duplicate of duplicate of duplciate

Answer (score 0):

you have to either execute the famous

```
SET NAMES charset
```

query where `charset` is your HTML page charset
Note that utf-8 in mysql would be `utf8`

or (preferred, but works only in the newest PHP versions) set the encoding in DSN:

```
$dsn = "odbc:DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=$hostname;DATABASE=$database;charset=UTF-8";
```

Answer (score -1):

Change from latin1 to utf8. And yes123 is right.